# Insert picture to Github page?

Tags: html, github, markup

How do you insert an image to the Github README, so that it shows up when loading a Github page that uses the README as the source?

I have written this code in my README:

```
<img src="https://github.com/my_username/xxx/blob/master/image.jpeg" width="1000"/>
```

When I look at the README in the repository, the image shows up. However, when I open my Github page (which uses the Jekyll theme), the picture shows up as a broken image symbol.

I would much appreciate some guidance! Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [shown here](https://talk.jekyllrb.com/t/i-cannot-get-an-image-to-display/850/3), try instead  to place your image in another folder (not something with an _ underscore). Create `/assets/images/` in the root of your project and place the image there.

Then in your README.md, you can reference it with either HTML or Markdown

```
![image](/assets/images/your-image.jpg)
```

(to avoid putting *all* images in the same folder, see the [jekyll-postfiles](https://nhoizey.github.io/jekyll-postfiles/) plugin)

Check that is displays in both GitHub and GitHub pages after Jekyll processed your project.

Comment: I created the following path in my Github master branch now: assets/images/picture.jpeg. However the picture won't show up when I do: ![picture](/assets/images/picture.jpeg). Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @erha Do you have the URL of your repository, for me (and others) to inspect?

Comment: Solved it, thanks a lot! I had put the picture file path between <p></p>, that's why your solution at first didn't work.

Comment: @erha Great: What was the correct syntax/organization?

Comment: This was the correct way: ![picture](/assets/images/manhattan.jpeg), just like you said

Comment: @erha So, what I mentioned in the answer, then? `![image](/assets/images/xxx)`

Answer (score 0):

i resolved it by importing the img

```
import img from './assets/img.png'
```

the you use it normally:

```
<img src={img} />
```

it worked for me